# PHP Regex - parsing large files

Tags: php, regex

I have a very large files -- some reaching up to 10GB -- that contains mostly structured data (e.g. 99% of it a tab-separated values for each line of text I'm interested in). I need to extract from these files very specific pieces of data that I can easily find via regex. However, my concern is that I'm going to run into all sorts of problems if I try to, say, convert the file into a string and then regex that string.

What's a good strategy for regex parsing very large files?

Comment: The best strategy is a very, very fast computer, sadly :/

Comment: @N.B. It's not solution, because even the best computer can't load string bigger than 2GB in PHP. It have to be read in chunks.

Comment: It depends. What kind of data do you have in that file? If you need data that is constrained to single lines, reading line by line is your best bet. If the parts you need are across lines, you might find a way to get chunks of lines or something to identify relevant groups.

Comment: Why would you use PHP for that, and not plain Unix tools (namely `grep`)?

Comment: @madfriend - you're assuming the code will always be in a *nix environment, which it will not. Also, I'd like an OS-agnostic solution.

Comment: @ElonThan - that's a pretty bold statement, could you provide a source that says you can't load a string larger than 2GB in PHP? Also, note that I haven't mentioned PHP anywhere. Whatever language you use, 10 gig file to parse is a timely operation. Whether you read it in chunks or not, fast computer is what wins the execution here.

Comment: Use some typed language, Java, Python. Line wise input, as regex normally should not be used for larger data. (More the issue that regex is hard to repair, as it has its own running strategy.)

Comment: @N.B. This thread is marked with `PHP` tag ;) You can find information about mentioned 2GB in php manual, at http://php.net/string But you're also right, fast computer will help a lot with such operation, even with use of chunks.

Comment: @ElonThan - it's not about where I can find it, it's about your statement's credibility. So, if there's a limit of 2GB, it's not hard to split the thing into 5 pieces. However, the best strategy still remains the fastest computer, no matter what language is used. Regex library is basically the same across any language. Whether C or Java or anything else is used, the strategy is to load the thing (if you can't chunk it) and process 1 by 1. Sadly, it is 2013. and we still have problems with large file parsing :/

Comment: @N.B. "the best strategy still remains the fastest computer" <-- hardware is not considered when computing an algorithm's computational complexity.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - great comment, I can instantly feel that tons of 10 gig or larger files are now being parsed faster after this divine revelation by you. I hope you're feeling proud for making the world a better place :)

Comment: @N.B. - no clue why you've become sarcastic, but "faster hardware" isn't the solution. If that were the case, we could have all stuck with a bubble sort and insist that it'll work just fine as long as we get a faster machine.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - if you can't tell why I'm sarcastic, then good luck to you in this field of science.

Comment: @N.B. My guess is that you've become defensive because you were called out on the fact that "faster hardware" is not really the solution here. Anyway, `fgets` seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie - just in order to clear this mess out so we're at the same page here - the most efficient algorithmic method is to process the file in chunks. However, after determining the most efficient algorithm - in order to speed up parsing of a 10 gigabyte file to a level where it doesn't take countless hours - a fast hardware is what levels the playing field. There is only so much you can achieve with the algorithm, not taking into account possible parallelism.

Comment: @N.B.: I'm actually parsing a daily 9GB file (100M+ lines) using `fgets`, `preg_match` and inserting/updating each line into SQLite as I go. Doing it on a lowend 2.2Ghz VPS with 256MB of RAM and the process takes ≃ 22 seconds per 10M lines. The whole thing is over in like 5-6 minutes.

Comment: @AlixAxel - thanks for the additional insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the file line by line (fgets) and process it in chunks.